# BelongstoMany relationship between a table and itself

Tags: cakephp, database-design, many-to-many, cakephp-3.x

I have a database with a table Users and i need to store information about one relationship between them: users that have permissions to manage other users. Also those managed users can be managers too, so any user can be manager or be managed by any other user including themselves (2 users can be managers of each other).

So the only idea coming to my mind is to create a "join" table with these fields:

```
manager_id (key field that links to a user_id)
managed_id (key field too that links to a user_id as well)
```

But a join table between the same table, which kind of relationship will produce?

Users->belongsToMany('Users') ??

Is this okay?

---

### (EDIT after ndm answer)

I'm getting an error using the approach ndm told me.

So, in UsersTable.php i have now:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Managers', [
            'className' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'manager_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id'
         ]);
```

In database "test.sql" table managers_users has 2 fields:

```
manager_id
user_id
```

both key fields

But when i try to query from UsersController.php:

```
$query = $this->Users->find()
                ->contain(['Managers'])
                ->all()
                ;
```

I get error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.users_users' doesn't exist

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join table usually involves a `belongsToMany` association, which is basically a combination of `hasMany` and `belongsTo` under the hood, and could also manually expressed as such, it could also be expressed using `hasOne` and `belongsTo`, it really depends on the needs of your application, so you probably should first asses how your application needs to query the data in what situation, and then go from there.

Generally self-associations are fine (see the introduction in the Cookbook association chapter),, so yes, in pricipal that would be okay, however you'd need to setup/configure things a little different in order for this to work properly, that is that you'd need to use a unique alias, for example `Managers` instead of `Users`, and then either your foreign key fields need to be adapted to the conventions, ie `user_id` (managed user) and `manager_id` (managing user), or you would have to configure them accordingly in the association configuration:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Managers', [
    'className' => 'Users',

    //'foreignKey' => 'managed_id',
    //'targetForeignKey' => 'manager_id'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsToMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)**

Comment: Hi, ndm. First of all, thank you. I think i have understood your point, so finally i have configured the relationship as you suggested. However i'm getting error: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.users_users' doesn't exist" whenever i try to cast a find on database. I'll edit the question because I can't write code here in comments. Hope you could help me on this.

Comment: @Baalhug That's what the table is expected to be named by convention, it will use the table names of the two model classes involved, not the aliases used for the association. You can adhere to the conventions and rename your table, or configure the table name via the `joinTable` option, or [**use the `through` option**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option) to define a specific class name for the join table that either matches your table name (like `ManagersUsers`) or uses `table()/setTable()` to define the required table name to use.

Comment: With option: 
'through' => 'managers_users'
woks perfect

Thank  you very much