# How to create a self BelongsToMany relation in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, database-design, relationship, cakephp-3.0

I have a database with a table "projekte" (german word for projects).
Some of the projects have a relation to eachother.
So i would like to have a BTM relation.

I created a joinTable "projektverbindungen" with the following fields:

```
projekt_id
nebenprojekt_id
```

I found a similar question here: [BelongstoMany relationship between a table and itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113974/belongstomany-relationship-between-a-table-and-itself) and i tried the answer of ndm, but without success.

Here is my ProjekteTable.php

```
class ProjekteTable extends Table {
  public function initialize(array $config)
  {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('projekte');
    $this->setDisplayField('name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasOne('Projekteigenschaften', [
      'foreignKey' => 'projekt_id',
      'dependent' => true,
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Projekte', [
      'foreignKey' => 'projekt_id',
      'targetForeignKey' => 'nebenprojekt_id',
      'joinTable' => 'projektverbindungen',
    ]);
  }
}
```

Here ist my template (add.ctp)

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create($projekt);
echo $this->Form->control('name', ['class' => 'form-control']);
echo $this->Form->control('projekteigenschaft.projektverantwortlich');
echo $this->Form->control('projekteigenschaft.beschreibung');
echo $this->Form->control('projekte._ids', ['options' => $projekte, 'multiple' => true]);
echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

The first step, saving a project with a related project works as expected.
The `id` of the created project was saved as `projektverbindungen.projekt_id` and the `id` of the related project as `projektverbindungen.nebenprojekt_id`.

When i query a projekt without the relation to other projects like so:

```
$projekt = $this->Projekte->get($id, [
  'contain' => ['Projekteigenschaften']
]);
```

the query looks like this:

```
SELECT Projekte.id AS `Projekte__id`, Projekte.name AS `Projekte__name`, Projekteigenschaften.id AS `Projekteigenschaften__id`, Projekteigenschaften.projektverantwortlich AS `Projekteigenschaften__projektverantwortlich`, Projekteigenschaften.beschreibung AS `Projekteigenschaften__beschreibung`, Projekteigenschaften.projekt_id AS `Projekteigenschaften__projekt_id` FROM projekte Projekte LEFT JOIN projekteigenschaften Projekteigenschaften ON Projekte.id = (Projekteigenschaften.projekt_id) WHERE (Projekte.id = :c0 AND (Projekte.deleted) IS NULL)
```

And the debug of the result looks like:

```
"id": "6862279f-8134-401f-86ff-9278a3bfa5c3",
"name": "My Project",
"projekteigenschaft": {
    "id": "89d9e241-e700-4c31-9266-ee5717f2a0aa",
    "projektverantwortlich": "Blisginnis, Ralf",
    "beschreibung": ""
}
```

Everything works fine.

But when i add the projects to contain like so:

```
$projekt = $this->Projekte->get($id, [
  'contain' => ['Projekteigenschaften', 'Projekte']
]);
```

The query looks the same like above, but the entity looks a bit different:

```
"Projekteigenschaften": {
    "id": "89d9e241-e700-4c31-9266-ee5717f2a0aa",
    "projektverantwortlich": "Blisginnis, Ralf",
    "beschreibung": ""
}
```

Projekteigenschaften seems no longer to be a hasOne relation and "Projekte" gets totally ignored.

Anyone has an idea what i did wrong? Or should i prefer an other way of doing this?

**edit after ndm´s comment**

I tried defining the relationship like so:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Projektverbindungen', [
  'class' => 'Projekte',
  'foreignKey' => 'projekt_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'nebenprojekt_id',
  'joinTable' => 'projektverbindungen',
]);
```

and changed the add.ctp template like so:

```
echo $this->Form->control('projektverbindungen._ids', ['options' => $projekte, 'multiple' => true]);
```

But then it doesn´t save the relation.

I also tried to rename the joinTable to projekte_projekte. It didn´t seem to make any difference.

Then I tried to use the through-option, but the results of that were even worse.
So I continued trying to find a solution with the method described above.

**2nd edit**

projekverbindungen ist accessible in Projekt.php:

```
protected $_accessible = [
  'name' => true,
  'projekteigenschaft' => true,
  'projekte' => true,
  'projektverbindungen' => true,
];
```

Debug of requestData:

```
[
  'name' => 'My Project',
  'projekteigenschaft' => [
    'projektverantwortlich' => 'John Doe',
    'beschreibung' => '',
  'projektverbindungen' => [
    '_ids' => [
      (int) 0 => '809031f2-4ecd-4dfb-82d5-2c911286dd21'
    ]
  ]
]
```

Debug of entity after patching:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Projekt) {

  'name' => 'My Project',
  'projekteigenschaft' => object(App\Model\Entity\Projekteigenschaft) {

    'projektverantwortlich' => 'John Doe',
    'beschreibung' => '',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'projektverantwortlich' => true,
        'beschreibung' => true,
        'projekt_id' => true,
        'projekt' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'projektverantwortlich' => true,
        'beschreibung' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[hasErrors]' => false,
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Projekteigenschaften'

  },
  'projektverbindungen' => [],
  '[new]' => true,
  '[accessible]' => [
    'name' => true,
    'projekteigenschaft' => true,
    'projekte' => true,
    'projektverbindungen' => true
  ],
  '[dirty]' => [
    'name' => true,
    'projekteigenschaft' => true,
    'projektverbindungen' => true
  ],
  '[original]' => [],
  '[virtual]' => [],
  '[hasErrors]' => false,
  '[errors]' => [],
  '[invalid]' => [],
  '[repository]' => 'Projekte'
}
```

**3rd edit**

In my bootstrap.php i have this:

```
Inflector::rules('plural', [
  '/^(projekt)$/i' => '\1e',
  '/^(projekteigenschaft|projektverbindung)$/i' => '\1en',
]);
Inflector::rules('singular', [
  '/^(projekt)e$/i' => '\1',
  '/^(projekteigenschaft|projektverbindung)en$/i' => '\1',
]);
```

After your recommendation I additionally added `propertyName` to the definition of the association:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Projektverbindungen', [
  'class' => 'Projekte',
  'propertyName' => 'Projektverbindungen',
  'foreignKey' => 'projekt_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'nebenprojekt_id',
  'joinTable' => 'projektverbindungen',
]);
```

After that, the patched entity looks like this:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Projekt) {

  'name' => 'My Project',
  'projekteigenschaft' => object(App\Model\Entity\Projekteigenschaft) {

    'projektverantwortlich' => 'John Doe',
    'beschreibung' => '',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'projektverantwortlich' => true,
        'beschreibung' => true,
        'projekt_id' => true,
        'projekt' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'projektverantwortlich' => true,
        'beschreibung' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[hasErrors]' => false,
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Projekteigenschaften'

  },
  'projektverbindungen' => [
    '_ids' => [
        (int) 0 => '1e28a3d1-c914-44be-b821-0e87d69cd95f'
    ]
  ],
  '[new]' => true,
  '[accessible]' => [
    'name' => true,
    'projekteigenschaft' => true,
    'projekte' => true,
    'projektverbindungen' => true
  ],
  '[dirty]' => [
    'name' => true,
    'projekteigenschaft' => true,
    'projektverbindungen' => true
  ],
  '[original]' => [],
  '[virtual]' => [],
  '[hasErrors]' => false,
  '[errors]' => [],
  '[invalid]' => [],
  '[repository]' => 'Projekte'
}
```

But still no new entry in the table "projektverbindungen"

Comment: How exactly did you try to implement the suggestion in the answer of the linked question?

Comment: @ndm I edited my question and added an answer to your question.

Comment: Have you made `projektverbindungen` accessible in your (presumably) `Projekt` entity class? If not, try that and see if saving works. If it doesn't work, please use `debug()` with your patched entity and show what it looks like.

Comment: yes it is. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I should've seen that right away, according to the conventions, the association property name for `belongsToMany` is plural, but the inflector doesn't speak german, it's based on english language rules, so [**it will expect an `s` appended**](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=Projektverbindungen), ie `projektverbindungens`. Either use the `property` option to define a custom property name, ie `projektverbindungen`, add a [**custom inflection rule**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/inflector.html#inflection-configuration), or switch to coding fully in english.

Comment: updated my question again.

Comment: You've defined the property name with an uppercase `P`, but you're using it with a lowercase `p`.

Comment: I tried to change it to `'propertyName' => 'projektverbindungen'`, but now the patched entity shows an empty array `'projektverbindungen' => [],` again

Comment: Ok, there's also `class` used instead of `className` in the association config. The fact that this doesn't trigger an error gives away another problem, a database table named `projektverbindungen` exists, it's your join table, so you cannot use that name, that will totally mess up things, you need to use a name that is unique and describes the target, for example `Nebenprojekte`, which of course requires to adjust the fields and config accordingly.

Comment: ndm, you are fckn' awesome!!! Thanks man! You made my day!
Here and on GitHub, since CakePHP 1.3 I read hundreds or thousands answers of you, MarkStory and DerEuroMark to any kind of CakePHP issue. Your great support saved me so much time over years. Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last suggestion of ndm made the trick.
Now it works like expected. Thank you very much!

Here is the correct setup:

ProjekteTable.php

```
  $this->belongsToMany('Nebenprojekte', [
    'className' => 'Projekte',
    'foreignKey' => 'projekt_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'nebenprojekt_id',
    'joinTable' => 'projektverbindungen',
  ]);
```

Here I used the property `class` instead of `className`, that has been the biggest issue.
Thats really embarrassing, because in the Cookbook is the correct name of that property:
https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations

Nevertheless, perhaps anyone else makes the same mistake and this thread can help.

The second thing is not to use the jointable`s name as the name of the association.

The rest is just straight forward...

Making the association accessible in the Entity Class (Projekt.php):

```
protected $_accessible = [
  'name' => true,
  'projekteigenschaft' => true,
  'nebenprojekte' => true,
];
```

ProjekteController.php ("add" and "edit"):

```
public function add()
{
    $projekt = $this->Projekte->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $projekt = $this->Projekte->patchEntity($projekt, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Projekte->save($projekt)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('flash message'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('error message'));
    }

    $projekte = $this->Projekte->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('projekt', 'projekte'));
}

public function edit($id = null)
{
    $projekt = $this->Projekte->get($id, [
      'contain' => ['Projekteigenschaften', 'Nebenprojekte']
    ]);

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $projekt = $this->Projekte->patchEntity($projekt, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Projekte->save($projekt)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('flash message'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('error message'));
    }

    $projekte = $this->Projekte->find('list')->where(['id !=' => $id]);
    $this->set(compact('projekt', 'projekte'));
}
```

In the templates like add.ctp or edit.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->control('nebenprojekte._ids', ['options' => $projekte, 'multiple' => true]);
```

If you use another language than english, don´t forget to set the correct inflection rules.
bootstrap.php:

```
Inflector::rules('plural', [
  '/^(projekt|nebenprojekt)$/i' => '\1e',
  '/^(projekteigenschaft)$/i' => '\1en',
]);
Inflector::rules('singular', [
  '/^(projekt|nebenprojekt)e$/i' => '\1',
  '/^(projekteigenschaft)en$/i' => '\1',
]);
```